# PHP Cron Job set but not running

Tags: php, shell, url, cron

I have set corn job using

```
exec('echo -e "`crontab -l`\n* * * * * http://example.com/cron/sendsms.php" | crontab -');
```

I have seen this using

```
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
echo '<Pre>';
echo $output;
//o/p * * * * * http://example.com/cron/sendsms.php
```

Till this everything works fine.

If I run this url(http://example.com/cron/sendsms.php). then it works without any error.

But cron not excuting with set time. what is the problem?

Comment: Do you have shell acces?

Comment: No Brother. I dont have access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, your *crontab* contains the following line:

```
* * * * * http://example.com/cron/sendsms.php
```

The URL is invoked as a shell command as if you entered `http://example.com/cron/sendsms.php` in a terminal and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you want to call the remote PHP script, you should use an HTTP client, e.g.

```
* * * * * wget -qO /dev/null 'http://example.com/cron/sendsms.php'
```

The command above sends an HTTP GET request to the URL and prints the response to the null device (a common way to ignore the output).

---

As an aside, the way you append entries to *crontab* is incorrect in many respects.

You [shouldn't be using the shell `echo` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo), use `printf` instead.

Use `$(...)` for the command substitution instead of the back quotes, since a) it is impossible to build a nested command substutition, and b) the `$(...)` form is more readable.

Avoid complex shell constructs in PHP. If you need a complex shell construct, you should create a separate file for the shell script.

You might append the *crontab* entry with the help of `proc_open()` without the need for the shell pipes.